# Sitecore Create new Template item using SPE

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Problem Statement-
Assume predefined base templates and rendering are in place.

Want to create new template item using SPE.

1. Create Template Item using Template .
2. Update base template field using
   Raw values. {Template Item GUID}|{Template Item GUID} 
   Create Standard
   Values.
3. Add standard Layout rendering as raw values in standard ,
   which is again available, just need to assign.
4. Add insert options.

Any guidance to go about this using SPE.

Answer (score 3):

To create a template item with Standard Values in Sitecore with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE).
You can use some things like this:

```
cd master:\
$item = New-Item  -Path "/sitecore/templates/User Defined" -Name "testtemplate" -type "{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}"
$standardvalues = New-Item -Parent $item -Name "__Standard Values" -type $item.ID
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["__Standard values"] = $standardvalues.ID
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

I suspect that the insert options can add the same as the __Standard Values just edit the Insert options field. See also [Set-Layout](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Set-Layout.html) and [Add-Rendering](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Add-Rendering.html) for adding renderings.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I looked the tds item code and got all in place workign.